# How to create a transport from the Console one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, winston

At the moment I have this code:

```
const logger = new winston.Logger();

logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {
  level: environment === 'development' ? 'silly' : 'info',
  colorize: true,
  prettyPrint: true
});
```

But I want to be able to write

```
const logger = new winston.Logger({transports: [customConsoleTransport]});
```

How can I create `customConsoleTransport`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new instance of the `winston.transports.Console` as it's just a constructor function. You'll end up with something like this:

```
const customConsoleTransport = new winston.transports.Console({
  level: environment === 'development' ? 'silly' : 'info',
  colorize: true,
  prettyPrint: true
});

const logger = new winston.Logger({transports: [customConsoleTransport]});
```

Comment: Do you know why `logger.add` has two arguments? Why not just pass an instance of the transport?

Comment: Checkout the docs here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston. It seems .add can be used for a range of things including creating categories. It's probably just for easier internal development I'd imagine.